# Ctrl+Alt+Del and DirectInput

Tags: c++, windows-7, directinput

I am using DirectInput in C++ to acquire the mouse and keyboard for my program. This works fine and I re-acquire if I get the InputLost error.

However, when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> my program gets `E_ACCESSDENIED` when attempting to acquire, even when the program window is re-selected. This occurs even if I don't actually select an option within the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> window (just press cancel).

I am curious as to how a program is meant to recover input after this has happened. I am currently running Windows 7.

Comment: When you press Ctrl-Alt-Del, Windows switches to a desktop that you don't have permissions to access. You may have to keep trying until the normal desktop is restored.